# Make the keystone supported website live on DigitalOcean

Tags: digital-ocean, keystonejs

This is my server block nginx config, but I don't know what is the mistake. When I hit my domain name, it gives me the "404 Not Found".
Kindly help

server {

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/squareeducation.in/SE_WebApp/template/views/layouts;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html default.hbs;
server_name www.squareeducation.in;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.hbs/ =404;
        proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

 location ~ .*\.(img|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|js|css)$ {
        root /var/www/squareeducation.in/SE_WebApp/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

that means that your server cannot find where the files are located, also, I don't know your configuration, but if you are starting simple, you can try by just using:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/squareeducation.in;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html default.hbs;
server_name www.squareeducation.in squareeducation.in;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.hbs/ =404;
}

}
```

I personally always start from the simple stuff to troubleshoot. Put a basic index.html file on that route: `/var/www/squareeducation.in`

and see if it reads it, also apply the permissions: `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/squareeducation.in`

Here is a page with Nginx basic commands, it'll come handy:

https://elkepon.com/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Hope it helps